# readObject method of objectinputstream throw ClassNotFoundException when changed class package

Tags: java, serialization

I used `ObjectOutputStream` to wirte object keeping object of properties in computer. Unfortunately I get `ClassNotFoundException` when changed to class package name at special cases.

That important of my question is:

How can I get old properties in old class into the my changed class?

I have to resolve issue because I need old properties to keeping my applications is work.I'm sure properties are same correctly that only class name is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunately I get ClassNotFoundException when changed to class package name at special cases

Change it back. You can change a lot of things about a class without breaking existing serializations, but the package name isn't one of them. You need to study the [Versioning of Serializable Objects chapter of the Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html) to see what you can and cannot change. It's too late to have second thoughts about package names after you've already done some serializations, indeed after you've deployed your application. Leave it be.

There are other ways around this but I'm hoping you won't need them.

Comment: Thank you tell me this information but I need resolve the issue.

Can you tell me how to around? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround:

```
class Workaround extends ObjectInputStream {
    String className;

    public Workaround(InputStream in, Class<?> cls) throws IOException {
        super(in);
        this.className = cls.getName();
    }

    @Override
    protected ObjectStreamClass readClassDescriptor() throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectStreamClass cd = super.readClassDescriptor();
        try {
            Field f = cd.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(cd, className);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return cd;
    }
}
```

Now I can write an instance of Test1 and read it as an instance of Test2

```
class Test1 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int i;
}

class Test2 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int i;
}

ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("1"));
Test1 test1 = new Test1();
oos.writeObject(test1);
oos.close();
Workaround x = new Workaround(new FileInputStream("1"), Test2.class);
Test2 test2 = (Test2)x.readObject();
```

Comment: Thanks your reply and answer. I have several of question for your way.
Is must to exist two class ? Because I changed class package name in my case there will be only one existed.

Is possible to do this way and done well?

My english is not good very sorry. :)    Thank you.

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev, it works perfectly, only that for me it´s necessary to change:  Field f = cd.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");  --> Field f = cd.getClass().getDeclaredField("className");